# Equivalent of newusers for groups

Tags: users, administration

The newusers command is useful for adding or modifying users in bulk. Is there an equivalent command for managing groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't run across one or a reason to have one.  Then main use case for new users I have seen is to add the students for a class or some other group.  They would normally all belong to the same group.

Groups usually have a specific purpose. Unlike users groups don't usually come in groups.

Do you have a use case in mind?

Comment: I'm creating a remote administration tool. The general idea is that users and groups can be retrieved over SSH, configured using the tool, then updated to the server. A newgroups command is not an absolute requirement for this case obviously but it's apparent absence made me wonder if I was missing something.

Comment: @Joel: No I don't think you are missing anything there.  However, I would look at using LDAP to manage the users and groups rather than the flat files in /etc.

Comment: LDAP is the best option but I'm dealing with some legacy servers with interesting limitations. Maybe that's the problem I should be addressing.

Comment: @Joel: If you have legacy servers, you may just have to edit `/etc/passwd` or equivalent through `VISUAL=ed vipw` or even directly.

Comment: @Gilles: That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same, but you can use `gpasswd` to set all the members of a group:

```
gpasswd -M "user1,user2" group
```

More info:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gpasswd.1.html